# Cannot read registry entry

Tags: c#

I have encountered an issue trying to read a registry entry on Windows server 2008.  The puzzling thing is the code does work on a different server that is also 2008, but is R2.  I have checked and the registry entry is in place, and I ran the program as Administrator.  Below is a code sample. The regitry key returned by Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey is null. This is a 64 bit application

```
string strPath = "";
try
{
    //The registry key:
    //SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SnmpClient.exe
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(strKey))
    {
            try
            {
                //InstallDirectory
                if (!(rk.GetValue(strValue) == null))
                {
                    strPath += rk.GetValue(strValue).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
return strPath;
```

Comment: Does an exception get thrown?

Comment: What is the issue? Does it throw an exception and if so on which line and what is the exception?

Comment: Please provide more details on the problem.  We need to know if your application is being ran as a x86 or x64 application.  We also need the EXACT exception message and any code it references.

Comment: The regitry key returned by Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey is null.  This is a 64 bit machine.  I

Comment: Sounds like registry redirection.

Comment: Right. Is the machine where it works also a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Maybe the key is in fact null on that particular machine.

Comment: Graham Wager is right, that should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said if you're compiling your app as 32 or 64-bit.

If you are compiling the application as a 32-bit one, it'll get redirected to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ **Wow6432Node** \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths...

Either check that the correct key is there too, or compile in 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can open up the 64-bit hive.

```
var localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
```

Answer (score 0):

Graham Wager and Tom Brothers are both right with the suggested approaches. My 2 Cents from an issue I faced while running a Unit Test using VS 2013 and MSTEST:

When executing a method that read from the registry through the Unit test, a registry key that existed always came back as null on the Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubkey(string, bool) method. The issue was that the test settings made the **default processor architecture to be X86** and hence when running through the test, the **Wow6432Node** was being read.

Summary:

VS 2013 with MSTEST running on Windows 7 64 Bit

To ensure that the test runs in 64-bit, go to TEST -> TEST Settings -> Default processor architecture and select X64

**Note**: Wow6432Node is for 32 bit apps running on a 64 bit system